# I can't mapping this classes in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, class, mapping, abstract, extends

I'm trying to make the next case. I want to declare a POJO class (ClassA) to define my class, but I use other class (ClassB) which extends ClassA and have business logical.

This is the case:

```
//model object
public abstract class ClassA implements Serializable {

    private String att1;
    ...
    constructors...
    ...
    gettters and setters...
}

//Business object
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    //With all business logical.
}
```

This way, always that the model have changed I only need change ClassA.

I'm trying this many times... Is this possible? Is there a better method to make it?

Thanks,
  Juankar!

Comment: Business (and also data access) logic shouldn't be in your entity model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this link : [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

It is possible to define subclass, union-subclass, and joined-subclass mappings in separate mapping documents directly beneath hibernate-mapping. This allows you to extend a class hierarchy by adding a new mapping file. You must specify an extends attribute in the subclass mapping, naming a previously mapped superclass. Previously this feature made the ordering of the mapping documents important. Since Hibernate3, the ordering of mapping files is irrelevant when using the extends keyword. The ordering inside a single mapping file still needs to be defined as superclasses before subclasses.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <subclass name="DomesticCat" extends="Cat" discriminator-value="D">
      <property name="name" type="string"/>
 </subclass>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. On this way, when model is changed I only need change abstract class.

```
//model object
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
public abstract class ClassA implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Basic
  @Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME")
  private String att1;
  ...
  constructors...
  ...
  gettters and setters...
}

//Business object
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    //With all business logical.

    //Without field's annotations
}
```

Thank you so much,
Juankar!